# Entity Framework Core - Set foreign key column name in OwnsOne entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

Having following entities:

```
public class Driver
{
    public LocationMonitor locationMonitor {get;set;}
    ... some other properties...
}

public class LocationMonitor
{
    public Location actualLocation {get; set;}
    public Location previousLocation {get;set;}
}

public class Location
{
    public LocationTypeEnum locationEnum {get;set;}
    public int? locationPointId {get;set;}          // foreign key
    public LocationPoint locationPoint {get;set;}   // navigation property
}
```

I would like to have table Driver with columns

```
int location                 // LocationTypeEnum
int actualLocationPointId    // (nullable) foreign key to LocationPoint table
int previousLocation         // LocationTypeEnum
int prevoiusLocationPointId  // (nullable) foreign key to LocationPoint table
```

How to do that using Fluent API?

I've tried to configure it with Fluent API using IEntityTypeConfiguration derived class:

```
...
            driverBuilder.OwnsOne(driver => driver.locationMonitor,
                lmBuilder => {
                    lmBuilder.OwnsOne(lm => lm.actualLocation,
                        location => {
                            location.Property(l => l.locationEnum).HasColumnName("location");
                            location.Property(l => l.locationPointId).HasColumnName("locationPointId");
                            location.HasOne(l => l.locationPoint)
                                .WithMany()
                                .HasForeignKey("locationPointId");
                        });
                    lmBuilder.OwnsOne(lm => lm.previousLocation,
                        location => {
                            location.Property(l => l.locationEnum).HasColumnName("previousLocation");
                            location.Property(l => l.locationPointId).HasColumnName("previousLocationPointId");
                            location.HasOne(l => l.locationPoint)
                                .WithMany()
                                .HasForeignKey("previousLocationPointId");
                        });
                });
...
```

but have following warning while creating migration:

```
There are multiple relationships between 'Driver' and 'LocationPoint' without configured foreign key properties causing EF to create shadow properties on 'Driver' with names dependent on the discovery order.
```

And in generated migration there are 5 'foreign keys' columns created with names: `LocationPointID, LocationPointID1, locationPointId, previousLocationPointId, locationMonitor_previousLocation_previousLocationPointId`

and with 4 foreign keys defined for columns: `LocationPointID, LocationPointID1, locationPointId, locationMonitor_previousLocation_previousLocationPointId`

I've tried to define foreign keys 'outside' of OwnsOne definition like that:

```
driverBuilder.HasOne(driver => driver.locationMonitor.actualLocation.locationPoint)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("locationPointId");
```

But Fluent API does not allow to define such complex navigation property.

How to make it generate only 2 foreign keys with given column names when they are defined inside `OwnsOne` definition (nested)? Searched internet for so long and i'm out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

---

EDITED after comment from @IvanStoev

You are right @IvanStoev, I had references to Driver entity in LocationPoint:

```
    public ICollection<Driver> actualLocationDrivers {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Driver> previousLocationDrivers {get;set;}
```

which were unnecessary. They weren't even configured. After removing them it worked like a charm.

Comment: There is definitely some misconfiguration in the code you've posted, but I can't reproduce the exact issue as explained, just partially (getting only 1 additional column/FK `locationMonitor_previousLocation_previousLocationPointId`). Please include the relevant part of the `LocationPoint` class / configuration.